# Need to create bat file on windows server to move old (60 days) files from a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a Windows server.A new file every day uploaded on the server with my code, and I give access of that folder to my site users with FTP but I need to give only last 60 days old file to the user. I think I need to create a bat file to check every day folder and move the external files older than 60 days to another folder is this possible if yes then how. I am working on window server 2012 in c# code.

Comment: check the link http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#DateDiff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the built-in [`ROBOCOPY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) command from your batch file, scheduled via Task Scheduler:

```
robocopy "c:\source" "c:\dest" *.* /MOV /MINAGE:60
```

Comment: is robocopy move the files from one to another folder

Comment: i wonna to check dates from that all files and remove old then 60 days to another folder

Comment: /MOV tells it to move files to "c:\dest" and /MINAGE:60 tells it to ignore files newer than 60 days ago